# GetStorage returns null in flutter

Tags: flutter

trying to save some data using GetSorage in flutter app but when i leave the app and come back again all the storage is deleted. this is how i get my data from db

```
  final box = GetStorage();
  List<Mesure> measures = [];

if (box.hasData("measures")) {
  List<dynamic> records = box.read("measures");
```

and this how i update it when i have some thing to change

```
 setState(() {
  widget.mesure.sampleNumber = result.rawContent;
  measures.removeWhere((Mesure measure) => measure.id == widget.mesure.id);
  measures.add(Mesure.fromJson(widget.mesure.toJson()));
  box.write("measures", measures);
});
```

Comment: Where is this GetStorage from?

Comment: GetX storage https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use await before box.write() to ensure that the data is written

```dart
setState(() async {
  widget.mesure.sampleNumber = result.rawContent;
  measures.removeWhere((Mesure measure) => measure.id == widget.mesure.id);
  measures.add(Mesure.fromJson(widget.mesure.toJson()));
  await box.write("measures", measures);
});
```